# Term for recruited jobs section

Tags: word-choice

I am designing user interface for a job portal , candidates can view jobs they have applied for in the section "Applied Jobs" , also there is a sub section where they can view jobs they have already got selected by various recruiters .

I'm confused about English term that should be used for that particular sub section which shows jobs for which candidate was selected earlier .

> "Recruited jobs" will be correct term to use ?

Any help,
Thanks

Comment: When you say "selected", do you mean for an interview or a job offer has been extended?

Comment: @Peter , selected = when a candidate gets job offer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just call it

> Offers Received
>   Job Offers

to specify offers made by hiring companies.

> recruited jobs

would usually mean jobs a potential employee is being asked to consider (recruited for), before a job offer is made.